# How detach and Attach entity with JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(1);
user.setName("Alex");//I want to save it
user.detache()
user.setAge(44);//I dont want to save it
```

How detach and Attach user with JPA `JpaRepository<User, Long>`

That's a fundamental principle of JPA. You work with attached (managed) entities, and every modification made on these managed entities is automatically made persistent but in same case I want to turn off it. How to do it in clean way?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Save only the name and not the age?

Comment: I want save only name not age and I dont want to write custom query I want to avoid boilerplate code

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You don't have the possibility *not* to set the fields you don't want updated?

Comment: Yes, every modification is immediately saved to the database. In my case I want to use it but sometimes I want to disable it. but if is not possible then I am gonna completely diable it for whole project

Comment: The modifications should only be saved when you call `JpaRepository<User,Long>#save`

Comment: no, data are saved immediately, after setName I see In logs SQL with update, also I checked it in database:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588565/spring-data-jpa-why-are-changes-to-a-returned-entity-automatically-persisted

Comment: That's a fundamental principle of JPA. You work with attached (managed) entities, and every modification made on these managed entities is automatically made persistent.

Comment: You might want to use a `@Transient` field for that.

Comment: I use @Transient, but I want to have controlon code level not annotation lvl

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795436/spring-jparepository-detach-and-attach-entity/26812963#26812963) is how you can add `detach()` method to your repository.

Comment: thanks, but that code is ugly I do not intend to implement this for all repositories

Comment: You can extend `JpaRepository` (say, `ExtendedJpaRepository`) and add `detach` and `merge` (equivalent to `attach`) methods to the interface. Then provide your own implementation which will be available to all repositories that extend your custom interface. See [my sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-hibernate) for an example of creating your own custom repository implementation.