# Is there any to use model object directly in @Query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am learning Springboot and till now I have reached JPA. I am able to do CREAT/READ/DELETE operations. But for UPDATE for a certain condition, I am facing the issue. Let me elaborate below:

**Rest API URL:** `http://localhost:8080/updateTopic?id=1`

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "name": "Update Test",
    "description": "This is PUT"
}
```

Here I do not want to pass `id` in request body rather I want to pass only the rest.
As JPA doesn't have any UPDATE operation so I have created a custom method in `Repository`.
Below is my code in Repository class:

```
@Query("UPDATE Topic set name = :topic1.name, description = :topic1.description where id = :id")
void updateById(@Param("id") int id, @Param("topic") Topic topic1);
```

But with the above code I got this error `antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node`. So after looking for a while on Internet somewhere it told to change to this below:

```
@Query("UPDATE Topic set name = :#{#topic1.name}, description = :#{#topic1.description} where id = :id")
void updateById(@Param("id") int id, @Param("topic") Topic topic1);
```

But this one is giving a runtime error like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-22T12:48:21.582+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE io.bootcamp.model.Topic set name = :__$synthetic$__1, description = :__$synthetic$__2 where id = :id]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE io.bootcamp.model.Topic set name = :__$synthetic$__1, description = :__$synthetic$__2 where id = :id]",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE io.bootcamp.model.Topic set name = :__$synthetic$__1, description = :__$synthetic$__2 where id = :id]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE io.bootcamp.model.Topic set name = :__$synthetic$__1, description = :__$synthetic$__2 where id = :id]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:370)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.updateById(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat io.bootcamp.service.TopicServiceImpl.updateTopic(TopicServiceImpl.java:44)\r\n\tat io.bootcamp.controller.TopicController.updateTopic(TopicController.java:37)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:919)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE io.bootcamp.model.Topic set name = :__$synthetic$__1, description = :__$synthetic$__2 where id = :id]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1508)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1553)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\r\n\t... 65 more\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE io.bootcamp.model.Topic set name = :__$synthetic$__1, description = :__$synthetic$__2 where id = :id]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.errorIfDML(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:314)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1507)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)\r\n\t... 80 more\r\n",
    "path": "/updateTopic"
}
```

Any way by which I can achieve my aim ?

Comment: Update your query then You can replace `@Param("topic") Topic topic1` with two separate parameters. `void updateById(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name, @Param("description") String desc)` and then pass values accordingly.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare what if there are more than 4-5 columns. I want to make a generic solution

Comment: Then the below solution is the way to achieve this. Find topic by id, update the required fields. You don't need to write a query for this one. Even you want to update multiple fields, you need to just call setter methods of the topic for those fields.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no update method because Hibernate manages the entity for you.**

Hibernate manages your entities for you. What this means is that any changes to existing entities are automatically passed through to the database, see the following SO answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589352/6342972

So basically what you need to do is use the `Topic findById(int id)` method to find the specific `Topic` you want to update and then update the specific fields of that `Topic`. Those changes are then automatically persisted in the database by Hibernate.

Comment: can't I use custom query like the above I written & pass the values from the model ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a query to update an entity? Hibernate is more or less designed to update entities like I described. I suppose you could pass the values as separate parameters: `@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Topic t set t.name = :name, t.description = :description where id = :id")
void updateById(@Param("id") int id, @Param("description") String description, @Param("name") String name);`

Comment: actually, I want to design the query as generic like for learning this is 2 columns but in the future, there can be more than 2 also. That's my new reason